# Downloading new files from FTP server to Windows in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am writing a batch file that downloads files from an FTP server.

Now, I want these files to be checked against the existing files, so that they are not being downloaded again. There are multiple files being downloaded and I do not know the name of the files that may be present in the FTP server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use any Window command-line FTP client that supports synchronization.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can use a batch file like:

```
@echo off
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=synchronize.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "synchronize local C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

References:

- Guide to [automating synchronization from FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [Scripting command `synchronize`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize).

You can have WinSCP GUI [generate a batch file template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Sure, note the `ftp://`.

Comment: ' @echo off 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"^
/log="C:\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul/log=synchronize.log\script="script.txt"^
open ftp://rnan:J13@Files8.cyberlynk.net/ ^
"lcd /D "C:\Users\rnan\Desktop\Batch Files\""^
"cd kgptel\"^
"mget*"^

synchronize local -delete "C:\Users\rnan\Desktop\Batch Files\"^
exit '


**Hey when i put that code, its opens a session in which i have to manually put down the commands. Am i doing something wrong ? or is that the way it behaves?


I was hoping the commands would be executed once i execute the bat file. Please help. **

Comment: You must have some syntax error in the code. But we cannot help you, if you post it in this unreadable format. Use pastebin or similar service

Comment: `\script="script.txt"` is wrong. Replace is with `/command` - Use the generate script function!

Comment: This may do: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /log="C:\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /command "open ftp://rnan:J13@Files8.cyberlynk.net/" "lcd ""C:\Users\rnan\Desktop\Batch Files""" "cd kgptel" "synchronize local -delete" "exit"`

Comment: Are you sure about the `-delete`, though?

Comment: Umm i just wanted the code to work, i will change it to replace or something else. The code that you gave me also opens a session and require me to type the code in the session. Not exactly sure what should i be doing so that the codes are executed when we execute the bat file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help though!

Comment: No, the code I have posted does not prompt for anything. If it does for you, you have not copied it verbatim. Show us a screenshot of the console window, showing both commands (remove the `@echo off`) and the output + Show us your exact script (again, use https://pastebin.com/ or similar service).